# Spell Check Algorithm

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I am implementing an Spellcheck algorithm for my informatics class in c

Special requirements are:

- everything in the main function
- no string class allowed
- keep it simple (for further reimplementation in assembler)

So I am stuck now. I created a program but I cannot image how to implement it without `strstr` or `sscanf`.

My Code:

```
int main() {
  char c;
  int index;
  int len = 0;
  char a[10000];
  char s[100];
  char *e;
  char ch = ';';
  char p = '.';

  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    a[index++] = c;
  }

  char *test;
  test = a;
  char *start;

  while (*test != ch)
    *++test;

  e = test;
  *e++ = 0;

  int k = 0;
  while (e[k] != p) {
    k++;
  }
  e[k] = 0;
  int x;
  int i, j, counter = 0;

  for (x = 0; 1 == sscanf(e += x, "%99s%n", s, &x);)
    if (strstr(a, s))
      printf("*%s* ", s);
    else
      printf("%s ", s);
  puts(".");
}
```

Any idea how to rewrite it? Especially i am looking for a `sscanf` alternative.

EDIT:
the input is declared as followed:
XY BCDE BX CDE CDEF;BCDE XY UV ABC CDE BX X A CDEF.

This is the input string. It is divided into 2 parts by a ;

The first is the dictionary. the second after the ; are the words to check.

If the word is known, I need to print it on `stdout`. If not I print it with `"*"` surrounded.

Comment: .: How are you checking whether a spelling is correct? You have to somewhere store the correct spellings.Isn't it?

Comment: Fail on readability.  Single-letter var names.

Comment: at the moment strstr is checking for me....

Comment: My compiler says `*++test;` has no effect.  Did you want `++test`?

Comment: this actually works. i just want to increase the pointer until i find a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you would need to contain a dictionary to do the spell-checkings. A trie would be very useful for representing the dictionary and for doing quick spell-checks.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Dictionary_representation